# Xcode 4: library depends on itself issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode4

On the project I'm helping to revive, [iSoul](https://github.com/arranger1044/iSoul), some users are reporting an [issue](https://github.com/arranger1044/iSoul/issues/8) while compiling with Xcode 4 (I use Xcode 3.6.8 currently and cannot get my hands on the new one at the moment): it appears that some libraries depend on themselves.

This is the message they are getting:

```
File /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iSoul-ervmuugfdxbpmohhmtpcemztfvyw/Build/Products/Release/libevent.framework depends on itself.  This target might include its own product.
File /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iSoul-ervmuugfdxbpmohhmtpcemztfvyw/Build/Products/Release/libXMLFramework.framework depends on itself.  This target might include its own product.
```

I have no clue about it, I checked the dependency targets but no one appears to depend on itself, plus it works fine under the previous version of Xcode. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

UPDATE:
Some other users say that when they try to build it with Xcode 4 the build seems to go fine but it fails to create a snapshot (reason: cannot go beyond a symlink) and so it stops. Disabling the creating snapshot feature in the preferences does not help, since the app does not run, even if it says the build step went fine.
Can someone please download it and confirm the issue?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to spend the $5 to get Xcode 4 so you can confirm the issue with the project you are trying to revive yourself?

Comment: I was hoping to delay the transition to Lion and Xcode 4 (my mac is not so up-to-date). I guess I will get to Xcode 4 sooner than expected at this point. Nevertheless, if I can confirm the issue, I will still have to solve it : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that your target is not included in the project details.

Check the project info

Go to Build Phases > Copy bundle resources and check that your project name is not in the list.